# I want to do a switch case or elif on Discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I did a simple bot that autoreacts on a Discord channel to messages from a specific user, but now I want to do the same thing but to multiple users with differents emojis, I tried this code, but it only works without the elif condition, any suggestions?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext        import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ",")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready...")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
      if (message.channel.id == channel_id and message.author.id == user_id):
            await message.add_reaction("")
      elif (message.channel.id == channel_id and message.author.id == another_user_id):
            await message.add_reaction("")

bot.run("bot_token")
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you tried logging the `message` parameter when you try to run the function, for example?

Comment: Are you seeing an error?  Does the original conditional still work?  Have you double checked the value of `another_user_id`

Comment: @AMC thank you, I did a debug and it's working now.

Comment: @GersonGMR You should post an answer, then.

Comment: @AMC I got the same error, but now after doing a second elif condition, idk what happened, when I hit the bot.py to execute it, it closes itself after 1 second

Comment: I don't know what happens, sometimes it runs, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @GersonGMR could you show the error message?